Counterpart of Safari "enable content blockers" in Firefox
In Safari, when we browse site A, there is an option Safari --> Settings for "address of site A" --> enable content blockers. Some websites do not function well unless this is unticked. But where is the counterpart option in Firefox?
All in MacOS.

Which operating system are you running on? Is it iOS or macOS? Content blockers are typically just ad-blockers (although some other extensions might function as a content blocker, though I don't have a specific use case). I don't use any Firefox extensions so I'm not sure for Firefox. I suspect you will need to use the extension button located near the URL bar (at least on macOS Firefox) to disable the ad-blocking extension for that website? Additionally, you might need to reduce tracking protection settings to make the website function correctly if it's set to "strict".

I think you'll need to disable to the extension using the extension icon located to the right of the URL bar in Firefox. Depending on the ad-blocking extension you use, it might just be a quick toggle to temporarily turn off ad-block for that website or all websites (until you toggle it back on). Note: Even if you've turned off ad-blocking, some websites (especially ad-supported streaming services) might not function correctly if your tracking protections settings are set to "strict", so you might need to set tracking protections to "standard". This is in addition to disabling ad-block.

@AVelj Tried extensions and I did use "standard". Does not work.

What’s the ad-blocking extension you use?

@AVelj Actually not using one. Tried disabling other extensions like greasemonkey, flash player, .... No effect.

So disabling all extensions didn't fix the issue? Then there are a few other possibilities, like are you running in private browsing? Using a VPN? Did you accept cookies? Some website functionality won't work without first accepting cookies. If you don't see the cookie banner at all, it suggests something is blocking it (i.e. an extension). The only other issue that could be causing it is if that particular website wasn't designed for Firefox's web engine Gecko. Most should function correctly, but some web developers are lazy to design for other  web engines and only design for webkit/chromium

When I say some website functionality won't work without first accepting cookies, an example is healthline.com, which if you don't accept their tracking cookies and you are located in the EU (where GDPR is in force), they will just flat out block you from using the website (but it should why you've been blocked because of EU's GDPR laws). So, maybe you've accidentally blocked a particular website's cookies previously and it's doing something similar to healthline? If so, you could try clearing cache/cookies and it should prompted you with the cookie banner again.

I did some more research, and found this reddit post which suggests maybe the language settings in firefox are causing the issue, or your privacy protections are still blocking it (even though they are set to "standard"?) see: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/102a6u4/website_blocked_on_firefox_only/ Alternatively, maybe it's a DNS setting in Firefox that's causing the site to not function properly, especially if its Geoblocked (though it doesn't explain why Safari works?) see: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/1c9s66s/why_am_i_able_to_use_reddit_blocked_in_my_country/
